# Structured logging with custom attributes

Tags: quarkus, logstash-logback-encoder, jboss-logging

Is there a way to do structured logging in JSON format with additional custom attributes per logging event using jboss-logging? I'm basically looking for something to replace [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/tree/logstash-logback-encoder-7.2#event-specific-custom-fields)'s `StructuredArguments`.

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this extension:

https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-logging-json